# Getting null from context

Tags: java, servlet-filters, dropwizard

Why am I getting resourceInfo as null in this. Is there any other way to get resource class and resource method?

```
@Provider
@Authenticate
@Transactional
public class TestFilter2 implements ContainerRequestFilter {

  private final SessionRepository sessionRepository;

  @Context
  public ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

  @Inject
  public TestFilter2(SessionRepository sessionRepository) {
    this.sessionRepository = sessionRepository;
  }

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    check();
  }


  private void check() {
    sessionRepository.getActiveSessionBySessionId("dsfsdf");

  }
}
```

Comment: Try to use the same type of injection points for both dependencies, i.e. either both field or bother constructor. Also are you registering there filter as a class, through scanning, or manually instantiating it and then registering it?

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score -1):

`@context` annotation doesn't allow you to inject `ResourceInfo` type, [here](https://dzone.com/articles/jax-rs-what-is-context) are the types that you can inject using `@context` :

> - SecurityContext
> - Request
> - ResourceContext
> - ServletConfig
> - ServletContext
> - HttpServletRequest
> - HttpServletResponse
> - HttpHeaders
> - UriInfo

Comment: Even these are also coming null.

Comment: did you solve it?